# Structure a Haskell project for user-friendly handling of "plugins"

Tags: haskell, plugins, haskell-stack, template-haskell

The question is how to structure a Haskell project in order to allow the user of a library to provide own *plugins* without having to mix her own code into the library's source code. Let me elaborate...

Suppose I have a library called `foolib` that

- provides plugins via a `Plugin` type class
- provides some (many) types that are instances of the `Plugin` class
- shall allow the user to create own plugins

Of course the user of `foolib` could just add more plugins inside `foolib/`. But `foolib` is developed independently of the application that uses `foolib`, and both are under separate SCM. In this case mixing in the user's plugins under `foolib/` violates separation and complicates source control. In short: Mixing in users' plugins in `foobar/` is feasible, of course, but can't be maintained.

The obvious alternative is depicted below. The user maintains `my-project`, adds `foolib/` as a git submodule (let's say we're using *git*), and keeps his plugins in a separate `Plugins/` directory. Now here comes the dilemma: All the plugins, i.e. both the user's plugins and the ones in `foolib`, are used  deep down in `foolib/src/Core/` and re-exposed to the user - not directly, but in disguise. (Suppose the plugins are *blocks* in a CMS where the plugin renders some HTML and makes some keywords available that the end-user can use in his content, and that are understood by a HTML template engine.)

[image: file structure]

One issue is how to make Haskell `stack` deal with this setup while keeping up with the separation of `my-project/` and `foolib/`.

To make matters worse, there is some template Haskell ("TH") going on that discovers all plugins in `foobar/src/Plugins` at compile-time and uses the class functions of the many plugins in many places in the source code of `foolib`. (This isn't perfect either since, to my knowledge, imports cannot be templatized - but that's another issue.)

I think it's clear that the structure I presented here isn't working and I don't see a nice way out. The central problem is that either I sacrifice the separation of `foolib` and `my-project`, or I end up with convolution of template Haskell, `sed`, `awk` and other scripts, which is ultimately counter-productive.

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It would be very beneficial for you to look at the **Snap** framework, because they have dealt with this exact problem using their *snaplets* framework. Snaplets are developed externally, and Snap is developed externally. When you want to make a Snap website, you import both Snap *and* the snaplets into your application, then instantiate them together.

http://snapframework.com